# Does each child add reactive getters and setters to props?

Tags: vue.js

Imagine you have a huge list of things to do:

```
[
   {
     id: 1,
     name: Pet a cat,
     priority: 'extreme'
   },
   ...
]
```

The app has three components grandparent -> parent -> child

The todo list is declared in grandparent's `data` function. This is where the list becomes reactive first. The list is then passed from grandparent to parent and from parent to child as a prop. From my limited understanding each component in the chain adds their own `getters` and `setters`. My concern is that this way of passing props is not optimal for performance. I mean, should I restructure my code in a way that minimizes such props passing or not?

Comment: There are several caveats that can bite you when passing props down through multiple levels this way _if_ multiple levels intend to manipulate that data. Generally speaking, if multiple components need to act on the _same_ data, I prefer to use a [vuex store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) instead of passing props that way they all have a single "source of truth"

Comment: @WesleySmith, I plan on emitting events so that only grandparent could decide what kind of data manipulation to perform. What I wonder is how much computaional load this approach adds

Comment: It will add load, there will be multiple copies, though its doubtful you'd ever notice it.

Comment: @WesleySmith, If you had to guess how much more load compared to vuex approach?

Comment: Hard to say, it would depend on how the code is written, what it does with the data, the size of the data, how often the data is changed, etc. General rule of thumb though is to not try to optimize your application until its clear that it needs it though. ie, if it works and is fast enough for your needs, its fine.

Comment: @WesleySmith, thank you, sir! Have a good day or night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **Props in Vue are readonly**. You'd get a runtime error if you ever try to update one. So actually there's no setters for parent and child components, only for grand-parent.
If your child components wants to update it, you'll have **to send events** until some component can actually update the data.

Second, you won't have any performance issue with it, it's the way Vue works and it's good at it. Actually it's the proper and most straightforward way to achieve what you want. Obviously, if the parent / child list extends even more, it's gonna be a pain for you to use only props + events, but no performance issue I think.

The other solution to avoid data to be passed through each component descendent is to use a "Vuex Store". This is not super easy to set up and understand for beginners though. You may give it a try if your app is becoming more complexe.

I'd suggest you to stick with your current solution as it has nothing wrong.

Happy coding :)